# nose piercing infected while fasting with blood

Tags: sawm, ramadan

As-salaamu 'alaykum I have a question, I was fasting today, I have a infected nose piercing and while I was cleaning there was blood that came out of it, is my fasting still valid? the blood was tiny amount that you.
please reply back to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the only things that invalidate fasts are eating or drinking and semen emission (wet dreams don’t count). There may be some other things but these are the ones I know of so if anyone knows please feel free to add them. Jazakallah Khair.

Also you didn’t drink the blood did you?

Comment: No I didn't there was only small blood. Jazakallah Khair for answering.